# Log of days' visited by a user - suitable datastructure?

Tags: database-design, data-structures

I am making a web app, and I want to include a feature which keeps log of all the days a user has interacted with the website, exactly like Stackoverflow does it:

[image]

What datastructure would be suitable for this?

I have thought of having A table with users' id's as columns and all the days as rows but that is just the most intuitive answer and would consume lot of space.

There are no special Queries that I have to run. Just shows the days in a calender (as shown in the image) and count the total number of days and consecutive days (as in the image)

Any suggestions as to what would be the optimal way? How does Stackoverflow does it?

Comment: "optimal" really depends on exactly what queries you want to run in which ratio. What are these "most intuitive answers" that you've thought of?

Comment: @Dukeling There are no special Queries that I have to run. Just shows the days in a calender (as shown in the image) and count the total number of days and consecutive days in the image.

Comment: Don't expect any definitive answer as to what [so] does - for that you'd have to ask on [meta], but that assumes that they'd be willing to reveal this information - and, given that [so] isn't open source, there's probably only so much they'd be willing reveal about the internals of the site, so I'm not even really sure that asking there would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get around needing to store each day visited for each user, otherwise you obviously won't be able to recall this information. If you were to simplify it to just storing a count of the days, this could be done with just two values per user - last visited day and count of visited days.

I would not make user ID's columns, as adding a column to a table is an expensive operation (probably requiring that the entire table be recreated). A better idea is to store a user ID, day pair in each row.

```
Table Visited
  ? - Column ID (Primary key)
  Column UserID
  Column Day
```

If properly indexed, most operations I expect you want to do should be lightning fast.

My *guess* is that this is how Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange does it.

Note that this is really a negligible amount of data compared to what Stack Overflow stores - if you were to simply post a comment each day, you'd already be well over the amount of data required to store that you were online that day.

An alternative is to have a bitmap of days for each user. I believe Stack Overflow has been around for just over 5 years, that's ~2000 days, so ~2000 bits, ~250 bytes. Once you consider that you should probably at least double that for the next five years (and you'd need to cater for the day you run out of space in this bitmap), querying it isn't particularly nice and/or efficient with most interfaces, and that many users may not have visited the site more than a handful of times, this isn't looking like such a good option compared to the visited table suggested above.